# What is "old" in the age of a wine?

Tags: idiom, adjective, participle, time, cibus

If I were to say "this man is 40 years old" in Latin, I would say *hic vir 40 annos natus est*.
That is, I would use the participle *natus* instead of any adjective meaning "old", and it is my impression that this is idiomatic.
(Please correct me if I am wrong!)

But how do I say "this wine is 40 years old"?
Should I use a translation of "old", the participle *natum*, some other participle, or yet something else?
I could say *hoc vinum 40 annos abhinc factum est* or something similar, but that feels like a circumlocution and unnecessarily heavy.

Comment: _Annos habere_ came to my mind, but I'm not sure it is old enough.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have found three ways of referring to the age of wine, the first of which is the most common and simplest:

**An adjective such as *anniculus, bimus* etc.**

> ***quadrimum** Sabina, o Thaliarche, **merum** diota*
>
> fetch the **four-year old wine** from the Sabine jar, o Thaliarchus
>
> Horace, *Odes*, 1.9

---

> *ponite turaque **bimi** cum patera **meri***
>
> set down incense and a bowl with **two-year old wine**
>
> Horace, *Odes*, 1.20

See also: Horace, *Satires*, 2.8.47 (*quinquennis)*; Varro, *On Agriculture*, LXV (*anniculus*)

**Stored for *x* years**

> *genera ... quae quanto pluris annos **condita** habuerunt*
>
> [there are] types [of wine] ... which the more years they have been
> stored
>
> Varro, *On Agriculture*, LXV

This sense of *condo* is also used for preserving and pickling.

**Pressed during the time of *x***

Using *premo* + an ablative absolute:

> *tu **vina** **Torquato** move **consule** **pressa** **meo***
>
> you, bring out the **wines pressed** **when my Torquatus was consul**
>
> Horace, *Epodes*, 13.6

See also Horace, *Epistles*, 1.5.4

**Bonus: wine that is older than *x* years**

> *est mihi **nonum superantis annum** / plenus Albani cadus*
>
> I have a jar full of Alban wine that is **more than nine years [old]**
>
> Horace, *Odes*, 4.11

Answer (score 8):

There is a direct quote for this situation in the Satyricon, where Petronius just uses *annus* in the genitive plural:

> Statim allatae sunt amphorae vitreae diligenter gypsatae, quarum in cervicibus pittacia erant affixa cum hoc titulo: FALERNVM OPIMIANVM **ANNORVM CENTVM**. Dum titulos perlegimus, complosit Trimalchio manus et: "Eheu, inquit, ergo diutius vivit vinum quam homuncio. (Petr. Satyr. XXXIV)

The labels on the amphorae remind me of this joke:

[image: XKCD 363]

Comment: Genitive of quality, I'd say.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that there's no difference between specifying the ages of people, and those of anything else.

The verb I would choose here is conficio:

*Hoc vinum est XL annos confectum.*

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense to always use a participle of a verb describing creation, whatever it may mean for the entity in question.