# What verb is wine made with?

Tags: vocabulary, verbs, word-choice, roman-culture, cibus

Which verb did the Romans use for making wine?
I can imagine saying *vinum facio/conficio/primo* and maybe some other options as well.
Different verbs might emphasize different aspects or steps of making wine.
What verbs are possible in such use?

This question was inspired by [an earlier one about the age of wine](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4549/79).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cato Maior devotes a large subsection of *De Agri Cultura* to wine. You can read the entire text [here](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/L/Roman/Texts/Cato/De_Agricultura/G*.html), and as can be expected, he sticks to very simple verbs:

general:

- making: vinum Graecum sic **facito**

actual wine making:

- plucking grapes: Hoc vinum [= has uvas] seorsum **legito**
- trampling grapes: In orculam **calcato**
- pressing grapes: Manu **conprimito** acina
- soaking grapes: **conbibant** noctem et diem
- mixing: ne **conmisceas** cum cetero vino

in recipes:

- blending: Vinum **concinnare**
- boiling: Ubi **bullabit** vinum
- cooling off: Ubi id vinum **refrixerit**

drinking !

- pouring: pridie quam vinum **infundere** voles
- drinking: **bibito** ante cenam

Varro also wrote a *De Agri Cultura* treatise. I've looked whether he is a bit more creative in his choice of words, but he isn't. In fact, he hardly mentions how to press wine, he focuses rather on which types of vines to plant etc.

Comment: Is there a particular verb used for "fermenting" wine?

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually quite surprised that Cato uses simply *facere* for making wine. This might be his simplification, but I guess we have to look at other authors to figure it out.

Comment: @R.M. yes, there seems to be: you can check the English version on the same website as the Latin text, and it translates the verbs *effervere* (115) and *fervere* (125) to ferment. Both instances are closely tied to the word *mustum*, which exists as an English loanword: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Must

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Cato uses the word *facere* hundreds of times in the course of *De Agri Cultura*, for all kinds of things